# patching while testing flask app causes AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I am trying to write tests for a Flask app.

Currently I have a test that looks like this in a file called test.py.

```
import mock
from test_helpers import mock_volume_views_setup

class UserTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp():
        <some set up>

    def tearDown():
        <some tear down>

    @mock.patch('brain_db.views.volume_views_setup')
    def test_labeled_scan(self, mock_volume_views_setup):
        # test that if path to atlas exists in the container,
        self.register_and_commit_user()
        self.login_profile_consent()
        self.upload('static/test.nii.gz', 1, '04/04/2008', 'GE', '1.5T')
        rv = self.app.get('/label_view/1', follow_redirects=True)
        response = str(rv.data)
        assert "MRI not labeled yet" not in response
```

test.py lives a top level directory, flask_brain_db.

In flask_brain_db/brain_db/views.py lives the route I'm trying to test.  A highly simplified version:

```
from brain_db_helpers import volume_views_setup

@app.route('/surface_test')
def surface_test():
    return render_template('brain_db/surf_view.html')

@app.route('/label_view/<int:scan_number>')
@login_required
def label_view(scan_number):
    a, b, c, d = volume_views_setup(scan_number, resource_type='atlas')
    if os.path.exists(a):
        return render_template('brain_db/scan_view.html')
```

When I try to run my test, I get

```
FAIL: test_labeled_scan (test.UserTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1297, in patched
    arg = patching.__enter__()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1353, in __enter__
    self.target = self.getter()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1523, in <lambda>
    getter = lambda: _importer(target)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1210, in _importer
    thing = _dot_lookup(thing, comp, import_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1199, in _dot_lookup
    __import__(import_path)
  File "/usr/src/app/flask_brain_db/brain_db/views.py", line 36, in <module>
    @app.route('/surface_test')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1250, in decorator
    self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 66, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1221, in add_url_rule
    'existing endpoint function: %s' % endpoint)
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: surface_test
```

I understand what this error is trying to communicate.  Somehow my patch decorator is, in an import, re-executing code that defines the routes in views.py, leading to the error. (The error doesn't appear without the patch decorator and mock function).  But I don't understand why, or how I am supposed to patch my helper method.  I have really struggled with understanding the correct way to refer to the method that needs patching, but looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29834693/unit-test-behavior-with-patch-flask) for example I think I'm doing it right.

Comment: `from test_helpers import mock_volume_views_setup` vs `def test_labeled_scan(self, mock_volume_views_setup):` , they share the same name, it is sign of trouble

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  Either I am extremely confused about patching or my abbreviated code is unclear.  I have to pass the test function my mocked function as an argument, no?  In any case, I think I've figured out how to get around this with code restructuring, and should probably answer my own question.

Comment: It is a route endpoint issue, how about add endpoint, such as `/surface_test` or function name `surface_test`, `@app.route('/surface_test', endpoint='surface_test')`?

Comment: or set `endpoint='other_function'`

Comment: I'm still struggling with understanding what you mean. I want to respect your efforts to help, so I tried adding endpoint='surface_test' to the decorator and it didn't make a difference.  I have moved past this problem.  The only thing inhibiting me from answering my own question is there's something about getting my patches to actually execute the mocked function I don't yet understand, so I can't confidently provide an example of working code, but I don't have this error anymore (because I just moved the business logic out of the route definition and then imported that function in).