# Understanding where to patch

Tags: python, python-unittest.mock

In [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch), it explains why patching at at the function definition level doesn't work:

> Imagine we have a project that we want to test with the following
> structure:
>
> ```
> a.py
>     -> Defines SomeClass
>
> b.py
>     -> from a import SomeClass
>     -> some_function instantiates SomeClass
> ```
>
> Now we want to test `some_function` but we want to mock out `SomeClass`
> using `patch()`. The problem is that when we import module `b`, which we
> will have to do then it imports `SomeClass` from module `a`. If we use
> `patch()` to mock out `a.SomeClass` then it will have no effect on our
> test; module `b` already has a reference to the real `SomeClass` and it
> looks like our patching had no effect.

The core explanation is *"module `b` already has a reference to the real `SomeClass`"*, but I don't fully understand the concept here. Can someone give me a deeper explanation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unit Test Behavior with Patch (Flask)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29834693/unit-test-behavior-with-patch-flask)

Answer (score 0):

The key is understanding what *name* `some_function` uses to access the class, not where the class is defined.

There are two ways you could have written `some_function`:

1. Accessing an attribute from the module `a`

   ```
   import a

   def some_function():
       x = a.SomeClass()
       ...
   ```
2. Accessing a global variable defined in `b`

   ```
   from a import SomeClass

   def some_function():
       x = SomeClass()
   ```

In the first scenario, you would need to change what `a.SomeClass` refers to. In the second scenario, you need to change what `b.SomeClass` refers to.

Answer (score 0):

An analogy:

```
a = {'SomeClass': 1}

# importing `from a import SomeClass`
b_SomeClass = a['SomeClass']

# patching
a['SomeClass'] = 2

print(b_SomeClass)  # still 1, because `b_SomeClass` is unrelated to the dict
```

```
a = {'SomeClass': 1}

# importing `import a`
b_a = a

# patching
a['SomeClass'] = 2

print(b_a['SomeClass'])  # 2, because we are referencing the thing 
                         # that changed: the dict
```

Modules are just objects in Python, so this is an especially close analogy.